# Is there any way to combine the logic of these two sql delete operations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing two DELETE operations in SQL. The first one deletes an entry in the database that has a student role name set. The second one deletes an entry where name is `null`. I'm wondering if I can have one SQL command that can handle both logic, or do I need to keep them separate?

I have 4 tables `Student`, `Class`, `Student_Role`, and `Signup`. The delete below will delete an entry where a user provides a unique ID of a student, a unique ID of a class, and the name of a student role.

Signup has 3 columns (CLASS_ID, STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_ROLE_ID) which are all foreign keys

```
1st DELETE command:

DELETE S FROM SIGNUP S
INNER JOIN CLASS ON CLASS.ID = S.CLASS_ID
INNER JOIN STUDENT ON STUDENT.ID = S.STUDENT_ID
INNER JOIN STUDENT_ROLE ON STUDENT_ROLE.ID = SDR.STUDENT_ROLE_ID
WHERE CLASS.UNIQUE_ID = :classUniqueId AND
STUDENT.UNIQUE_ID = :studentUniqueId AND STUDENT_ROLE.NAME = :roleName
```

But if I pass `null` for `roleName`, then this query won't work. Basically my second use case is I want to delete a record where student unique ID and class unique ID matches with what the user provides, but the role name doesn't exist. In this case, it's `null`. So I have another `DELETE` statement for that case:

```
2nd DELETE command:

DELETE S FROM SIGNUP S
INNER JOIN CLASS ON CLASS.ID = S.CLASS_ID
INNER JOIN STUDENT ON STUDENT.ID = S.STUDENT_ID
WHERE CLASS.UNIQUE_ID = :classUniqueId AND STUDENT.UNIQUE_ID = :studentUniqueId
AND S.STUDENT_ROLE_ID IS NULL
```

Now I'm wondering if I can combine these two into one statement that can handle either condition (user provides a specific student role ID, or role ID is `null`) At the end, only one entry should be deleted. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: *"But if I pass null for roleName, then this query won't work."* `AND STUDENT_ROLE.NAME <=> :roleName` should do the trick?  The `<=>` operator is MySQL's `NULL` safe check.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if I understood you, but maybe this is what you want

```sql
DELETE S 
FROM   signup S 
       INNER JOIN class 
               ON class.id = S.class_id 
       INNER JOIN student 
               ON student.id = S.student_id 
       LEFT JOIN student_role 
              ON student_role.id = S.student_role_id 
WHERE  class.unique_id = :classUniqueId 
       AND student.unique_id = :studentUniqueId 
       AND ( ( :roleName IS NULL 
               AND S.student_role_id IS NULL ) 
              OR ( :roleName IS NOT NULL 
                   AND student_role.NAME = :roleName ) )
```

Changed the STUDENT_ROLE from INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, and in the where clause "ignore" the STUDENT_ROLE.NAME check if :roleName is NULL.

Comment: sorry, I tried to make my question as clear as possible. I think this might be what I'm looking for! I'll give it a try and comment back if it works

Comment: seems to not work. This is deleting both entries where role name is `null` and where role name has a value

Comment: @RonApple1996 I've updated the answer in a way that may work for you. If not, you can edit you question to include schema of all table and samples of records for each one. Mark the records you want to delete by this query.